# shell script to get added lines of a file

Tags: shell

I get a large log file which I have to process.
After a week, I'll get a new one. It will be the same with added new lines (logs).

I just need the new added lines.

How do I do that?

EDIT: I've tried sed so far but haven't been successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`diff`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) would allow you to find any and all differences between these files, as long the changes are restricted to added and/or removed lines. On most Linux distributions it's a part of [GNU diffutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/), but it exists on pretty much every Uinix-like system.

Comment: funny I didn't get to this solution myself. Thanks. I haven't found the means to take away the trailing "< " automatically, so doing 
"diff file1 file2 | sed s/\<\ //"...

Comment: @fabfile: Try: `diff --old-line-format='' --new-line-format=$'%l\n' --changed-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format='' log1 log2` (unfortunately, it's much more verbose than using `sed` and is probably not very portable).

Answer (score 0):

If line are append to log file and I suppose you have the old one, you could try :

```
tail -$(( $(cat newLogFileName | wc -l)-$(cat oldLogFileName | wc -l) )) newLogFileName
```

Comment: Two UUoCs! Try `wc -l < filename`.

Comment: Damn, I'd better think before post... Little question : UUoCs means ?

Answer (score 0):

`comm -13 oldfile newfile` will get you the lines that only appear in the newfile.

Comment: That may complain about unsorted files under some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

```
# get new.log
tail -n+$(($(wc -l < old.log)+1)) new.log
mv new.log old.log
```